# Outline in FireFox Quantum gets expanded by child divs

Tags: html, css, firefox, firefox-quantum

I stumbled across a strange behaviour in FireFox Quantum, where the outline of a div seems to be expandable by absolute positioned child divs:

```
<div id="outer-div">
  <div id="inner-div">
    <div id="terrible-expander"></div>
    hello outline
  </div>
</div>

#outer-div {
  background-color: gray;
}

#inner-div {
  background-color: green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  position: relative;
  outline: 2px solid red;
  outline-offset: -2px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#terrible-expander {
  height: 20px;
  width: 3px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
}
```

This example looks as expected in Chrome:

[image: outline in chrome]

and is messed up (IMO) in Quantum:

[image: outline in quantum]

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nrLy5c1q/11/)

**My question**

Is there a way, to align the behaviour of FireFox Quantum to that of Chrome in this case?

Comment: I don't see where the question is in this. Are you asking whether this is indeed a problem, or what should be the expected behavior?
If you believe this is a bug in Firefox, I recommend you to report it through BugZilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/

Comment: @TimVisée I added a question and will open a bug report as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it, so both browsers behave the same, by moving the property `position: relative;` from `#inner-div` to `#outer-div`.
Here is the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nrLy5c1q/24/)